# Using jQuery .click function to click watch for a click on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a website using Bootstrap, Node.js, and jQuery for a club.  I am trying to write a piece of Javascript code that when an image (or preferably the div it is in) is clicked on, another javascript function I have to change the pdf displaying will run.  My problem is nothing works to catch a click on the image.

My code for the image:

```
<div id="2005d" style="cursor: pointer">
    <img id="2005p" style="max-width: 100%" src="/magazines/2005_cover.jpg">
    <h5 id="2005t" style="text-align: center; color: black">2005</h5>
</div>
```

The jQuery I am trying ot use to catch a click on this image:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#2005d").click(function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

What can I do to try to get jQuery to catch the click event on the image?

Comment: try $("#2005d").on('click', function(){...});

Comment: The code you posted should work, do you get any errors on the console? At page loading or when you click the div?

Comment: Is there div in question loaded during page load or is it created dynamically? Try `$(document).on("click", "#2005d", function() { //your stuff here});`

Comment: Since you have the click handler attached on the parent div(`#2005d `), due to `event bubbling` any click events inside the child will be caught by the parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JQuery Event Delegation to set up the handler on the parent element, but test to see if the event originated on the image and use the JQuery `.on()` method instead of `.click()`, which JQuery recommends.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#2005d").on("click", "img" ,function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="2005d" style="cursor: pointer">
    <img id="2005p" style="max-width: 100%" src="https://image.spreadshirtmedia.com/image-server/v1/mp/designs/12386804,width=178,height=178/winking-smiley-face.png">
    <h5 id="2005t" style="text-align: center; color: black">2005</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is right but you have to write click event for image,, try this it works

```
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("#2005p").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked");
 });
});
```